# how to set more than 3 level of access permissions for a single file/folder?

Tags: permissions

normally I can only do 3 levels: owner, group, others
But I want 6 for group1, 5 for group2, 0 for all other groups
how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditional Unix permissions are limited to owner, group and other. But most modern unices support [access control lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). On modern Linux systems, ACL support is enabled by default in the filesystem, but you may need to install the ACL utilities `getfacl` and `setfacl` (e.g. on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint you may need to install the `acl` package).

```
chmod u=rwx,go= somefile
setfacl -m g:group1:rw -m g:group2:rx somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Access Control Lists (ACL)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-acls.html) to achieve finer control in file and directory permissions.